React App Blank Page When Deploying to Netlify
I could use some help troubleshooting an issue with deploying my React app on Netlify via GitHub. While the app works perfectly fine on my local server, I'm encountering a frustrating problem when deploying it – all I see is a blank white page with no error messages.
I've linked the GitHub repository here for reference.
And here's the live Netlify link: https://jocular-jelly-ef67db.netlify.app/
Here are my build settings:

If anyone has any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue or how to fix it, I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!

If you will see you are having an issue of noscript. You can check this https://answers.netlify.com/t/site-is-live-but-sill-blank-screen-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-app/72380, but as you do not have configuration file in the repo, so I don't think you have any redirect set. You can also check this: https://answers.netlify.com/t/site-is-live-but-sill-blank-screen-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-app/72380

thank you. I will check them out and try to work out a solution.

Try changing path={${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}} to path={'/'} and see if it works

I had a similar issue, and it was related to the homepage property in the package.json file.
The answers here were some variation of: replacing the url with a full stop, removing the url and leaving the quotemarks, or removing the property altogether.
I chose the second approach and it seems to be working for me.
